# Attach script to jQuery ready method before jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

For example, bootstrap put the jQuery at the end of the html, e.g. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html

What if, you want to insert a code block **before** the loading of jQuery script itself, e.g.

```
<div id="test1"></div> 
<div id="test2"></div> 

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#test1').html('test1'); // not work, any workaround? the code must be put before..
   });
</script> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#test2').html('test2'); // work
   });
</script>
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/e5HKZ/

I want both test1 & test2 also displayed.

Any idea?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Are you asking how to insert code in the head or something?

Comment: not sure what you are asking... but jQuery must be loaded before any code using `$` gets loaded, otherwise `$` will be undefined

Comment: I think what you are asking is achieved by using the document.ready block. Any code you put in there will only be executed once jQuery is ready, which seems to be what you are asking. Perhaps have another go at asking you question?

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the question and provided a jsfiddle link. Thx again

Comment: "*the code must be put before*" - Why? There is no good reason

Comment: @Bergi, becoz I have no access to the code below the line, think of I can only edit blog content, but cannot control all the page elements.

Comment: @Howard, only possibility is to warp your jQuery code in a JavaScript handler such as `window.onload = function(){ ... }`. Not recommended though, you should better fix the includes order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to put jQuery code before the line that loads jQuery itself, assign the function to `document.ready`.

```
window.document.ready = function() {
    $('#test1').html('test1');
};
```

When jQuery has been loaded, it reads the variable and executes the function at DOM ready.

Note that this is most likely undocumented behavior and might not work reliably or in future jQuery versions.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e5HKZ/1/

Comment: Never heard of `document.ready`. You may assign to it without an exception, but I'm sure it never gets called.

Comment: @Bergi So the demo doesn't work for you? Because it works for me.

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected, it actually gets called. However this is a (imho unintended) side-effect of jQuery triggering an `ready` event, and not native JavaScript! Unless documented somewhere, this should not be used, "support" for this "feature" can drop any time.